# Pass String variables by reference to setOnItemSelectedListener of multiple Spinners

Tags: java, android, pass-by-reference, android-spinner

OK, I've [read around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference) and see that Java only passes by value, not by reference so I don't know how to accomplish this.

- I've 6 Spinners in an Android Activity that are populated with different SQLite queries.
- The code to populate each Spinner and set the OnItemSelectedListener is very similiar so I was hoping to refactor to one method and call it 6 times with each Spinner ID and Sqlite query.
- How do I get the Spinner onItemSelectedListener to change the right instance member on each different Spinner?

  ```
  public void fillSpinner(String spinner_name, final String field_name) {
  // This finds the Spinner ID passed into the method with spinner_name
  // from the Resources file. e.g. spinner1
  int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(spinner_name, "id",
          getPackageName());
  Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(resID);
  final Cursor cMonth;
  // This gets the data to populate the spinner, e.g. if field_name was
  // strength = SELECT _id, strength FROM cigars GROUP BY strength
  cMonth = dbHelper.fetchSpinnerFilters(field_name);
  startManagingCursor(cMonth);
  String[] from = new String[] { field_name };
  int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };
  SimpleCursorAdapter months = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
          android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cMonth, from, to);
  months.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
  s.setAdapter(months);
  // This is setting the Spinner Item Selected Listener Callback, where
  // all the problems happen
  s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
      public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
              int position, long id) {
          Cursor theCursor = (Cursor) parent.getSelectedItem();
          // This is the problem area.
          object_reference_to_clas_member_of_field_name = theCursor
                  .getString(theCursor.getColumnIndex(field_name));
      }

      public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
          // showToast("Spinner1: unselected");
      }
  });
  ```

  }

You call this method like this `fillSpinner("spinner1","strength");`.

It finds the spinner with id `spinner1` and queries the database for the `strength` field. field_name, which is strength in this example had to be declared a final variable to be used in the onItemSelectedListener or I'd get the error `Cannot refer to a non-final variable field_name inside an inner class defined in a different method`.

But how do I get the onItemSelectedListener to change the value of a different instance member when each different Spinner is used? This is the all important line of code:
`object_reference_to_clas_member_of_field_name = theCursor      .getString(theCursor.getColumnIndex(field_name));`

I can't use a final String as the variable will obviously change when the user selects a different value. I've read around a good bit and am stumped to a solution. I can just copy and paste this code 6 times and forget about refactoring but I'd really like to know the elegant solution. Post a comment if you don't understand my question, I'm not sure if I explaned myself well.

Comment: actually, it is not clear what do you want and what problem you are facing in onItemSelected. Please elaborate more.

Comment: `Cannot refer to a non-final variable field_name inside an inner class defined in a different method.`, why don't you declare `field_name` globally in the main class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it, by passing additional class as parameter of `fillSpinner` method:

A. Create `interface`

```
public interface OnSpinnerValueSelected {
    void onValueSelected(String selectedValue);
}
```

B. Change your method a bit:

```
public void fillSpinner(String spinner_name, final String field_name,
                    final OnSpinnerValueSelected valueChangeListener) {

    // Prepare spinner

    s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                     int position, long id) {
            Cursor theCursor = (Cursor) parent.getSelectedItem();

            valueChangeListener.onValueSelected(theCursor
                           .getString(theCursor.getColumnIndex(field_name)));
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
}
```

C. provide listener:

```
fillSpinner("spinner1","strength", new OnSpinnerValueSelected() {
    public void onValueSelected(String selectedValue) {
        yourObject.setField(selectedValue);
    }
});
```

Comment: Great, this worked and just seems better than having hardcoded variable names in the refactored function itself. So in Java you can't pass a String object by reference, but you can pass a final object that has a method to set the value of the String object.

Answer (score 1):

Refactor your listener to a new "class". Initialize with the right arguments/instances as required so that the repeated "code" is reusuable.

Comment: Yes yes, that sounds about right. I'll try that and report back, cheers

Answer (score 0):

Right, this is how I managed it but I'm still open to new suggestions for an accepted answer and I also created a bounty.

I didn't create a new class like [panzerschreck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8905322/pass-string-variables-by-reference-to-setonitemselectedlistener-of-multiple-spin/8905440#8905440) suggested so I'm posting this as a new answer to my own question. Bit of a hack but I just created an if..then..else statement in the listener to check what spinner was selected and then set a different instance member.

```
s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            Cursor theCursor = (Cursor) parent.getSelectedItem();
            if (field_name.equalsIgnoreCase("strength")) {
                strength=theCursor.getString(theCursor.getColumnIndex(field_name));
            } else if (field_name.equalsIgnoreCase("ring")) {
                ring_gauge=theCursor.getString(theCursor.getColumnIndex(field_name));
            } else if (field_name.equalsIgnoreCase("country")) {
                country=theCursor.getString(theCursor.getColumnIndex(field_name));
            } else if (field_name.equalsIgnoreCase("wrapper")) {
                wrapper=theCursor.getString(theCursor.getColumnIndex(field_name));
            } else if (field_name.equalsIgnoreCase("length")) {
                length=theCursor.getString(theCursor.getColumnIndex(field_name));
            } else if (field_name.equalsIgnoreCase("price")) {
                price=theCursor.getString(theCursor.getColumnIndex(field_name));
            } 
            // showToast(category);
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // showToast("Spinner2: unselected");
        }
    });
```

Here are the class members

```
private String strength,ring_gauge,country,wrapper,length,price;
```

Bit of hack but without Java allowing objects to be really passed by reference, it's all I could do.

Comment: I must say its not a good practice to put 'if' statements. Avoid hard coded values too where ever possible, it's a maintenance nightmare !

Comment: I couldn't use a switch statement on Strings if that's what you meant. I know, I didn't want to use hard coded values either but what other choice is there. I'd love to know the elegant solution to this. I tried creating a new class as a listener like you suggested but again the problem is how I pass instance members by reference and not by value to the constructor of this new listener class.